# size of an array excel - json vba parser

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am using a vba json parser : https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON . I want to loop over the elements in the `B` array but I am unsure how to do this. e.g.

```
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJSON("{""a"":123,""b"":[1,2,3,4],""c"":{""d"":456}}")
```

If you want to get back the number of elements in `B` how do you do this?

You get back the actual value by doing the following : `Json("a")`

Comment: What does `Json("b")` give you? "[1,2,3,4]" or "1,2,3,4" or something else?

Comment: Json "b" gives you an error . "Run-time error '450'. This is because I need to specify which array I am accessing. So if i do Json("b")(1) I can get back the first element, which is 1. I also tried Len(Json("b)) but it does not work. Trying to figure out how to return the number of elements in the array then i can loop over them .. =/

Comment: How were you trying to get `Json("b")`? Have you tried the usual VBA array size functions? So, `LBound(JSon("b"))` and `UBound(JSon("b"))`? Or try `Json("b").Count` as the docs for vba-json imply it returns a dictionary/collection.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Do While ... Loop` loop till `Json("b")(counter)` returns no error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs for the source [vba-json](https://code.google.com/p/vba-json/) state:

> parse JSON and create Dictionary/Collection

So you will get back one of those objects. This seems to work:

```
Sub testJson()

Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""a"":123,""b"":[1,2,3,4],""c"":{""d"":456}}")

Debug.Print Json("a") ' -> 123
Debug.Print Json("b")(2) ' -> 2
Debug.Print Json("c")("d") ' -> 456
Json("c")("e") = 789

Dim var As Object
    ' Get the object from Json
    Set var = Json("b")
    ' Both Dictionary and Collection support the Count property
    Debug.Print var.Count

Dim elem As Variant
    For Each elem In var
        Debug.Print elem
    Next elem

Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Json)
' -> "{""a"":123,""b"":[1,2,3,4],""c"":{""d"":456,""e"":789}}"

End Sub
```

The "b" in the Json example returns a collection but for "c" you would get back a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you. What i needed. Spent hours for something so simple ¬_¬

Comment: @ ChipsLetten Hi ChipsLetten, I try to implement your solution in my own code although I do not succeed. I hope you can take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75596069/extract-maximum-of-a-json-array-in-excel-vba-without-iterating  thanks a lot!