# extract maximum of a json array in excel VBA without iterating

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have JSON data string from which I try to extract the highest value of "id" without iterating.

This is the JSON data string:

```
        "ball_coordinates": [
            {
                "id": 3938706,
                "fixture_id": 18795544,
                "period_id": 4644037,
                "timer": "17:20",
                "x": "106",
                "y": "57"
            },
            {
                "id": 3938771,
                "fixture_id": 18795544,
                "period_id": 4644037,
                "timer": "18:17",
                "x": "15",
                "y": "75"
            },
            {
                "id": 3939282,
                "fixture_id": 18795544,
                "period_id": 4644037,
                "timer": "28:47",
                "x": "21",
                "y": "19"
            },
            {
                "id": 3938083,
                "fixture_id": 18795544,
                "period_id": 4644037,
                "timer": "3:28",
                "x": "8",
                "y": "77"
            }
        ]
    },
```

The highest id is 3939282.

In the post below I noticed it is possible to count the items in a part of a JSON string:

[size of an array excel - json vba parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783798/size-of-an-array-excel-json-vba-parser)

If I change var.Count to var.Max it works too.

If I try to implement this method in my own Excel VBA code in the way below, it gives an error at line two (starting with Set myvar).

```
Dim myvar As Object
    Set myvar = item("ball_coordinates")("id")
    Debug.Print myvar.Count
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Max(myvar)
```

The error is: Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

I have the JsonConvertor-code activated in this workbook which runs fine.

I suppose the reason is that the id's are spread over all elements and not within one element as is the case in the other post.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

The reason for my question is that I try to increase the speed of my code. If I use the code below with iteration it takes 9 seconds to process 30k ball_coordinates.

```
highest_bal_id = 0
bal_timer = "NA"
bal_x = "NA"
bal_y = "NA"


For Each bal In item("ball_coordinates")

    bal_id = bal("id")
    If bal_id > highest_bal_id Then
    
        bal_timer = bal("timer")
        bal_x = bal("x")
        bal_y = bal("y")
        highest_bal_id = bal_id
    
    End If
    
Next
```

**EDIT 2:**

I also tried the alternative code below to see if this is faster. Although I do not succeed to access item("ball_coordinates")("id") based on the highest_ball_id. I do not know if it is possible to access it as a dictionary or collection with a key based on highest_ball_id.

```
teller = 1

For Each bal In item("ball_coordinates")

    temp_array(teller) = bal("id")
    teller = teller + 1
    
Next

highest_ball_id = WorksheetFunction.Max(temp_array)

Debug.Print item("ball_coordinates")("id"); highest_ball_id
```

**EDIT 3**

The json data string is nesting from a larger string.
The data is from an API and generated with this code:

```
Dim http As Object, json As Object, i As Integer, item As Object
Dim APIString As String
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
APIString = "https://api.com/livescores/inplay?api_token=__&include=periods;scores;participants;ballCoordinates"
    http.Open "GET", APIString, True
    http.send

Set json = ParseJson(http.responseText)

For Each item In json("data")

    'read every item for periods, scores, participants, ballCoordinates

Next
```

The complete data has this structure:

```
{
    "data": [
          {
            "id": 18796712,
            "sport_id": 1,
            "league_id": 2451,
            "periods": [
                {
                    "id": 4646720,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712
                }
            ],
            "scores": [
                {
                    "id": 12200589,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712
                },
                {
                    "id": 12200590,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712
                },
                {
                    "id": 12200545,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712
                },
                {
                    "id": 12200546,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712,
                }
            ],
            "participants": [
                {
                    "id": 24401,
                    "sport_id": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 11978,
                    "sport_id": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ball_coordinates": [
                {
                    "id": 4549595,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712,
                    "period_id": 4646720,
                    "timer": "03:25",
                    "x": "39",
                    "y": "25"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4549532,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712,
                    "period_id": 4646720,
                    "timer": "03:20",
                    "x": "39",
                    "y": "25"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4549466,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712,
                    "period_id": 4646720,
                    "timer": "03:14",
                    "x": "39",
                    "y": "25"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4549422,
                    "fixture_id": 18796712,
                    "period_id": 4646720,
                    "timer": "03:11",
                    "x": "39",
                    "y": "25"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 18560614,
            "sport_id": 1,
            "league_id": 603,
            "periods": [
                {
                    "id": 4646650,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614
                }
            ],
            "scores": [
                {
                    "id": 12200402,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614
                },
                {
                    "id": 12200392,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614
                },
                {
                    "id": 12200394,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614
                },
                {
                    "id": 12200401,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614
                }
            ],
            "participants": [
                {
                    "id": 4190,
                    "sport_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 286,
                    "sport_id": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ball_coordinates": [
                {
                    "id": 4549597,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614,
                    "period_id": 4646650,
                    "timer": "31:23",
                    "x": "0.42",
                    "y": "0.24"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4549579,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614,
                    "period_id": 4646650,
                    "timer": "31:20",
                    "x": "0.42",
                    "y": "0.24"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4549549,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614,
                    "period_id": 4646650,
                    "timer": "31:19",
                    "x": "0.61",
                    "y": "0.19"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4549483,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614,
                    "period_id": 4646650,
                    "timer": "31:14",
                    "x": "0.61",
                    "y": "0.19"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4549472,
                    "fixture_id": 18560614,
                    "period_id": 4646650,
                    "timer": "31:13",
                    "x": "0.41",
                    "y": "0.81"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You'll need to loop.

Comment: Given the JSON you posted and using VBA-JSON,  `ball_coordinates` would be a `Collection` object (which does have a `Count` property) containing one `Scripting Dictionary` object per contained item.   The only way to get the max. value (or any other measure) across all of the "id" key values in those dictionaries is to loop over them.

Comment: If you were open to PowerQuery then you could get the [Max of the Ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58gD7.png) - if you tagged your question as such someone would probably be able to give you much shorter syntax too

Comment: @ Spectral instance Thank you for your help. The reason I look for a solution without looping is because of speed. I will make an API call every second in VBA and process the response every second within VBA. Do you expect PowerQuery to be faster for this purpose than a loop? I expect it will be pretty hard to implement for me since I do not have experience with PowerQuery, although I did some expirmenting with it before.

Comment: Did you try looping ? If so, how long did it take ?

Comment: The processing time depends on the size of the response from the api. When I have 30k coordinates, it took 9 seconds to process. I have added my code to the question above.

Comment: @ Tim Williams Thank you for your help. If i do TypeName(Json), where Json is the received response from the api by : Set Json = ParseJson(http.responseText). The name is a Dictionary. TypeName(item("ball_coordinates")("id")) gives Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument. Based on your comment I tried to use a loop and Key as I added in EDIT2 although I do not succeed to use a Key since this code throws a similar Run time error 5.

Comment: I'm just an advocate for PQ and not an expert but, given the volumes it was designed for, getting the max out out of 30k rows wouldn't take anything remotely like 9 seconds;  with a pure VBA approach, you're having to involve several non-Excel objects: to make the request _and_ to parse the response, whereas with PQ that's all 'built in' so there is also less 'object communication' required - the only 'snag' with PQ is that the result is conventionally dumped to a worksheet but, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72122340/18824727) answer, it is possible to get it directly in VBA.

Comment: That `Dictionary` may also contain collections, arrays as items... So, what `item("ball_coordinates")("id")` object type is? If a dictionary, too, and it keeps (only) "IDs", you can try using `Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Max(myvar.items)`, but it will work only if all items represents ID values, **in an array**... It may also be a Collection, which cannot be used as argument for `WorksheetFunction.Max`...

Comment: @ FaneDuru Thanks! Unfortunately i can't assign item("ball_coordinates")("id") to myvar. I can't either TypeName(item("ball_coordinates")("id")). Both give: Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: @ Spectral Instance Thank you for your help. Although it is a too long road for me to learn PQ with the additional risk that I need to use the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally parsing json yourself with a regex is bad practice but for a simple case where speed is most important then it's an option. This should take ~0.2 seconds.

```vb
Sub MaxID()

    Dim fso, ts, regex, m1, m2, s As String, t0 As Single
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' load json from text file
    'Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("30001.json")
    's = ts.ReadAll
    'ts.Close

    ' or load from api
    ' add http code here
    s = http.responseText
    t0 = Timer

    ' create regex
    Dim ar, i As Long
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        
        ' ball_coord tags
        .Pattern = "ball_coordinates\"": \[[^]]*]"
        If .test(s) Then
            Set m1 = .Execute(s)
        Else
            MsgBox "No ball_coordinates tags"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        ' id tags
        .Pattern = "\""id\"": *(\d+)" ' "id": 3938083,
    End With
    
    ' iterate matches
    Dim max As Long, id, n As Long
    For n = 1 To m1.Count
        Set m2 = regex.Execute(m1(n - 1))
        For i = 1 To m2.Count
            id = m2(i - 1).subMatches(0)
            'Debug.Print n, i, id
            If id > max Then max = id
        Next
    Next
    
    ' result
    MsgBox max, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot CDP1802! I currenly do not succeed to replace 30000.json with the correct object. I have tried http.responseText and json both with or without "". Excuse me if my question was not clear in mentioning I did receive the data from an API and that ball_coordinates is nested in a larger object json("data"). I have added Edit 3 with details.

Comment: @user2165379 you can remove aĺl fso, ts code and use `s=http.responseText`

Comment: @ CDP1802 it runs without error although the identified maximum is from "fixture_id": instead of "id":. I suppose this is due to a nesting above where "id":. is also used for "fixture_id". I suppose this is very hard to solve. Alternatively I have tried to replace "id": with "timer\" in this way: "\""timer\"": *(\d+),". Although m.Count becomes 0 in this case. Maybe there is a problem that timer is a string? (That was the reason I choose to sort on id initially.)

Comment: @user2165379 "\""id\"" shouldn't match fixture_id, I don't know why that is, it doesn't in my tests. m.Count is 0 because the capture pattern is wrong for the timer values. I guess there is more to the json file than the part you showed.

Comment: @ CDP1802 "id" does not match "fixture_id" although "id" is used for "fixture_id" in a nesting above. So "id" is matched with "id" in another part of the data. Excuse me I did not provide my complete code from the start. I will try to adapt the capture pattern for timer values.

Comment: @user2165379 It might work with `.Pattern = "\""id\"": *(\d+).*fixture_id"`

Comment: @ CDP1802 I have added an example of the complete data structure (see Edit 3). The problem is that "id" is used several times in several nestings and is not unique for 1 nesting. Moreover there are multiple items in the data, each with there own ball_coordinates (and "id" 's). Due to this I suppose it will not be possible to use regex. It is my mistake that I did not had added the structure from the start in my question. Without the nesting strucure it is a very good idea to use regex for speed I suppose, so i accepted this as the answer. Thank you all a lot for your help!

Comment: @user2165379 I have updated answer to use 2 regex, 1st to extract ball_coordinates and the 2nd for id tags.

Comment: @ CDP1802 Thanks a lot. For some reason it only reports "No ball_coordinates tags" for every item, even when there are ball_coordinates.

Comment: @user2165379 That's odd because it tested OK with your latest sample data.

Comment: @ CDP1802 i will look into the string tomorrow. The data above is printed with Postman. Maybe it differs from the data response within VBA.

Comment: @ CDP1802 i have copied a part of the API-response below. The only difference I can see is that a space is missing (compared to the data in Edit 3) between : and [ after "ball_coordinates": This is the copy:  "placeholder":false,"last_played_at":"2023-02-26 10:00:00","meta":{"location":"away","winner":null,"position":6}}],"ball_coordinates":[{"id":5195198,"fixture_id":18781647,"period_id":4651234,"timer":"47:39","x":"0.57","y":"0.65"},

Comment: @user2165379 In that case add * after space ie `.Pattern = "ball_coordinates\"": *\[[^]]*]"`

Comment: it runs and it correctly takes the id instead of fixture_id. Although the maximum is the same for all items. It currently runs in 28 seconds (there is a large response from the API). My initial code currently runs in 55 seconds. While 28 is twice as fast as my initial code, it is still not fast enough since my purpose is to call it every second. I think I am going to look at an alternative with running/processing the API-response in R and call and import the output into VBA. Thank you very much for all your time! I readlly appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
Dim json As Object
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""ball_coordinates"":[ . . . ]}")

Dim ballCoordinatesCollection As Object
Set ballCoordinatesCollection = json("ball_coordinates")

Dim collectionItem As Object
Dim id As Long
Dim maxID As Long

maxID = 0
For Each collectionItem In ballCoordinatesCollection
    id = collectionItem("id")
    If id > maxID Then
        maxID = id
    End If
Next collectionItem

MsgBox "Maximum ID is " & maxID
```

Comment: @ Domenic Thanks! Initially I received run-time error 10001: error parsing json. After deleting the dots . . . between [  ] the code runs without error. Although maxID is 0 since ballCoordinatesCollection is empty. (Object json is a Dictionary. Object ballCoordinatesCollection is a Collection.)

Comment: You'll need to pass `JsonConverter.ParseJson()` the actual json string.

Comment: It runs now. I used Set ballCoordinatesCollection = item("ball_coordinates"), since ball_coordinates is nested in data. data is from Set json = ParseJson(http.responseText). "For Each item In json("data")" is where item comes from. It runs in exactly the same time as my original code. I will try if I can modify it as in Edit 2 so that I can use WorksheetFunction.Max instead of If id > maxID.