# how to improve speed in calling an API from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If I call WorksheetFunction.WebService in Excel VBA once a second, the received response is only updated once every 4 seconds.

Initially I noticed this issue between Excel and a local server on my local pc.
Although an external server gives the same issue. This can be tested with calling the code below which calls an api server for the worldtime once a second:

```
Sub speedtest()
    
    For f = 1 To 10
    
        my_http = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Amsterdam"
        my_output = WorksheetFunction.WebService(my_http)
        Debug.Print my_output

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            
    Next f

End Sub

>
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:10.288974+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:10.288974+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:10.288974+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:10.288974+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:14.205044+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:14.205044+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:14.205044+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:14.205044+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:18.227253+01:00"
"datetime":"2023-03-07T18:26:18.227253+01:00"
```

If the url is submitted and refreshed in Chrome, it is updating once a second correctly.

Is there a method in Excel VBA to receive an API-response every second?

I noticed that if I submit the url to Power Query it can be refreshed once a second, although I need the result in VBA and not in a worksheet where Power Query seems to need a worksheet.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I run a loop and call the service 10 times (without any break), it executes all 10 calls in less than a second. How do you trigger your routine? Is it really a problem of the call or is it a problem of your "wait" logic?

Comment: @ FunThomas I have added a loop and Application.Wait to the code. Please see my output above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a caching problem.
I wrote a small test routine that calls the service and pauses for 1s.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    Application.WebService ""
    Debug.Print i, Second(Now), city, Application.WebService("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Amsterdam")
    Sleep 1000
Next
```

The result looks like

```
1 :3       {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:04.072029+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211344,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:04.072029+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
2 :5       {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:04.072029+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211344,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:04.072029+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
3 :6       {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:04.072029+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211344,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:04.072029+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
4 :7       {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:07.381876+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211347,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:07.381876+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
5 :8       {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:07.381876+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211347,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:07.381876+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
6 :9       {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:07.381876+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211347,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:07.381876+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
7 :10      {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:10.757293+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211350,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:10.757293+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
8 :12      {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:10.757293+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211350,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:10.757293+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
9 :13      {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:10.757293+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211350,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:10.757293+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
10 :14     {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:49:14.623928+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211354,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:49:14.623928+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
```

So I changed the code by introducing a logic that changes the city, resulting in different URLs

```
Dim cities
cities = Array("Paris", "Amsterdam", "Berlin")
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 10
    Application.WebService ""
    Dim city As String
    city = cities(i Mod (UBound(cities) + 1))
    Debug.Print i & " :" & Second(Now), city, Application.WebService("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/" & city)
    Sleep 1000
Next
```

This gave me

```
1 :24         Amsterdam     {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:25.298976+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211785,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:25.298976+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
2 :26         Berlin        {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:27.031239+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin","unixtime":1678211787,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:27.031239+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
3 :28         Paris         {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:28.200192+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Paris","unixtime":1678211788,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:28.200192+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
4 :29         Amsterdam     {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:30.576139+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211790,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:30.576139+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
5 :31         Berlin        {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:31.760924+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin","unixtime":1678211791,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:31.760924+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
6 :32         Paris         {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:33.032718+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Paris","unixtime":1678211793,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:33.032718+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
7 :34         Amsterdam     {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:35.399453+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211795,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:35.399453+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
8 :36         Berlin        {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:37.108448+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin","unixtime":1678211797,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:37.108448+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
9 :38         Paris         {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:38.334731+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Paris","unixtime":1678211798,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:38.334731+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
10 :39        Amsterdam     {"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"2003:f8:af01:9e01:b035:2d9a:577:30e2","datetime":"2023-03-07T18:56:39.638523+01:00","day_of_week":2,"day_of_year":66,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","unixtime":1678211799,"utc_datetime":"2023-03-07T17:56:39.638523+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":10}
```

You see that the time constantly changes for every call.

(for the `Sleep`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638733/7599798)

Comment: @ FunThomas Thanks a lot! If I run both routines, I have the same outcomes as you. Do you expect the caching problem is within Excel or due to the website? If I call the website continious in Chrome there is no issue. The reason I did start testing this is because I had this issue with a local api on my pc which I hosted by myself at my local pc (not over the internet) with R-package Plumber. In this case I am running a loop in R every second which assigns the current time to a variabele which can be called from Excel VBA by the local API. In this case I have the same issue.

Comment: I guess this is somewhere within VBA - but you find hardly any documentation about that at all. But why do you need to provide the actual time by an API every second? But anyhow: Maybe you can modify the API to ignore a certain parameter and then fill that parameter randomly in the call?

Comment: @ FunThomas I concluded the same since Chrome and Excel Power Query do not have the issue. That is a brilliant idea to modify the API in the way you mentioned! I was thinking about set up multiple api hosts and call them one by one but this is better. I will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Calling the worldtime is just as a test for the issue. My real purpose is that I have to call an external api from excel VBA. Although the response is very large which cost a lot of time processing. Pls see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75596069/2165379  For that reason I want to make the call from R and process it within R. Next I want to set up a local API with Plumber so I can call R from Excel VBA by this local API.

Comment: @ FunThomas It runs perfect with the randomized parameter in the call! Thank you very much. I am very glad it could be solved!